# Wix 3.7 to fill in ui with current user information

Tags: wix, wix3.7

Is there a way to retrieve the current user's information (i.e. login/password) so that it may be used to automatically fill in forms during the install?

I do not know where to start my searching.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the answer to a similar question I found [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-get-the-current-user-in-WiX-td2394505.html):

> "Windows will never, ever give you the user's password. You will have to 
>   prompt the user to give it to you."

If this were possible, it would present inherent security problems. Consider what else a program could do if it could obtain my account credentials programmatically just because I am running the program.

If you just want the user name though, it looks you can get that with the LogonUser built-in variable. There is a list of built-in variables [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html) if you are interested in what else is available.

Comment: The list that is linked to is for Burn variables--those would be for a WiX Bootstrapper project. For a WiX Setup project, use [Windows Installer properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).